# Is there any way to reduce the size of tflite-model-maker?

Tags: tensorflow, data-science, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to run a notebook on deepnote/colab but I keep getting the same issue, everytime tflite-model-maker tries to install it just fills the disk entirely and can't install.
Deepnote is limited at 5GB of disk storage and colab is around 100GB but I keep getting the same issue on both notebooks.
Any help would be greatly appreciated ! Thanks in advance.